# Angular adding a body class depending on state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing, angularjs-routing

I have something like this working

```
  <body ng-app="ELT" ng-class="{'mapBody': $state.includes('map')}" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
```

So obviously what I am trying to do is add a class "mapBody" when the state is map

and my controller a such

```
  .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','$state',function ($scope,$state) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.$state = $state;
  }])
```

Is there a better way to do this ? Don't like the fact I had to had a new controller just for this one thing, plus it's a lot of logic in the html.

Comment: Try to check ui-sref-active directive... http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Radim Kohler Better way is, you could use the `ui-sref-active` directive.

To add the class active to your element when the ui-router state matches use

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="ELT" ui-sref-active="mapBody" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <a ui-sref="app"></a>
</body>
```

Whenever underlying `ui-sref` is current state then if will apply `mapBody` class to body.

See [Example](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active) here

**Edit**

In your case you want to append a class to body depending on state,
So using `ui-sref-active` in this case will not work. Because body can contain several `ui-sref` and at least one will be satisfied, class will always append to body. 
I believe currently the way you are doing is correct. 
But I'd like to suggest one change,
instead of assigning `$state` to controller each time. Do it in angular `run` phase only once.

```
//it will assign a state inside $rootScope and it will get available on each page 
app.run(function($rootScope, $state) { 
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
});
```

Above code will be more cleaner and it will avoid assigning $state inside scope each time.

Thanks.

Comment: Trying to understand the user so I need to do something like this on my body ui-sref="map" ui-sref-active="mapBody"

Comment: So to get this to work it needs an empty link under body tag ? seems a bit weird

Comment: No.. i gave example how to do it..On your page how many ui-sref are there?

Comment: Quite a few, but I can't see how it matters how many links on the homepage I have. I am just trying trying to add a body class on page depending on a state. because I want to add some different styling for my map view.

Comment: Then it would be quite difficult to manage using this directive..what `ui-sref-active` directive does is it goes through their inner `ui-sref` mentioned state..if it get satiesfied then it gave mentioned class to that element..

Comment: Ok cool yeah I can definitely see a use for it, but maybe not for a Body class I guess